# Script to nudge by 1/10 in Illustrator

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I wrote a script to nudge by 1/10 in Illustrator (like in InDesign). It works, but only for the whole object, even if I only select some anchors. Is there a way for it to work as well when only anchors (or paths) are selected?

Here is the script:

```
var myDis = app.preferences.getRealPreference ('cursorKeyLength'); 
var myDis = myDis/10 
var myDoc = app.activeDocument;  
var mySel = myDoc.selection;  

for ( var i = 0; i < mySel.length; i++ ) {  
mySel[i].top = mySel[i].top-myDis; // so it moves by 1/10 of the cursorKeyLength to the top
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came with, wich will move selected anchors to the left by 1/10 of the Keyboard Increment saved in the Preferences:

```
var myLength = app.preferences.getRealPreference('cursorKeyLength') / 10,
    mySelection = app.activeDocument.selection,
    myDistance = [0 - myLength, 0]; // move selected anchors to the left


for (var i = 0; i < mySelection.length; i++) {
    // for anchors 
    if (mySelection[i].typename === 'PathItem') {
        var p = mySelection[i].pathPoints;
        for (j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
            if (p[j].selected === PathPointSelection.ANCHORPOINT) {
                with(p[j]) {
                    anchor = [anchor[0] + myDistance[0], anchor[1] + myDistance[1]];
                    leftDirection = [leftDirection[0] + myDistance[0], leftDirection[1] + myDistance[1]];
                    rightDirection = [rightDirection[0] + myDistance[0], rightDirection[1] + myDistance[1]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // for anything else 
    else {
        with(mySelection[i]) {
            position = [position[0] + myDistance[0], position[1] + myDistance[1]];
        }
    }
}
```

To move the anchors in another direction, change variable myDistance:

```
var myDistance = [0 - myLength, 0]; // leftward
var myDistance = [0 + myLength, 0]; // rightward
var myDistance = [0, 0 + myLength]; // upward
var myDistance = [0, 0 - myLength]; // downward
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand *why* you need a script for this.....

Set the `Keyboard Increment` in the preferences to 5:

- Tap any arrow key -  <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> ... the nudge is 5
- Hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key down and tap any arrow key -  <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> ... the nudge is 0.5 (1/10 the increment setting) (**this only works in InDesign**, Illustrator won't recognize this)
- Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and tap any arrow key -  <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>  ... the nudge is 50 (10x the increment setting)

**This works with any selection** be it merely anchor points or whole objects.

You can get a 1/10 nudge of *any* value just by using modifier keys in InDesign. If using an action, the modifiers are recorded. If using Illustrator I just set my nudge to a very small amount, then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> when I need it larger.

But then, perhaps I just don't understand why you feel a script is necessary.

Comment: Your shortcut (cmd+shift) works very well in InDesign, but not in Illustrator, which is the app I was trying to code for. Thanks!

Comment: @Raphaël It works perfectly in Illustrator. I use it daily.

Comment: Your 1/10 nudge works in Illustrator with the cmd key? Not in mine... and I searched on forums and it is written everywhere that you can't in Illustrator (but cmd+shift works in InDesign).

Comment: Oh.. hmm... guess not. Seems your'e right the command/ctrl does not work in AI. Always thought it did. I just set my nudge to very small, then use shift when I need it larger. I'll edit the answer....